# Setting properties for logging in java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, java.util.logging

Before you read this, you should know that I am a python developer in uncharted Java territory.

I am trying to set up logging for Java. I was able to get it to work when I set the logging.properties. Like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file= /path/to/logging/file/logging.properties -jar start.jar
```

The `logging.properties` file is checked into revision control and in my current set up is to be used in all environments, so I don't want to hard code the logging.FileHandler.pattern in the `logging.properties` file. So, I tried to move that to the command line, by doing this:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file= /path/to/logging/file/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/var/log/project_name/solr/solr.log -jar start.jar
```

But it seems that the FileHandler.pattern wasn't recognized, so the the file never wrote. So, then I thought, well, let's just ditch the `logging.properties` file and try to throw everything on the command line. So, then I tried this:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -server -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.Handler=java.util.logging.FileHandler -D.level=WARNING -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/var/log/project_name/solr/solr.log -jar start.jar
```

But that didn't work either. So, I am asking for help.

Three questions:

1. Why didn't the second example I provided work?
2. Why didn't the third example I provided work?
3. Since the logging.properties file is checked into version control and is a shared file, what is the right approach to this? What is the best practice?

When responding, please used small words for us Java newbies. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `-Dxyz.blahbla.bla=foobar` is a System property, and not everything could be used as a System property, because there will be *some* code that will ask for that property, and even though you can put whatever you want, nobody will read it.

For instance, try this code:

```
class HelloSystemProperty {
     public static void main( String ... args ) {
         System.out.println( System.getProperty("getIt"));
      }
 }
```

And then run it like:

```
java -DgetIt=Yeah HelloSystemProperty
```

So, as you may guess by now you can't just go and put anything that goes into that file as a system property **UNLESS** you read it your self and process it accordingly.

So if you definitely NEED to modify the logging level by hand as a system  property you may want to [add code to read that property and set the values](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html#package_description), but probably that's too much and I'm not sure if you want to go there.

So using the file should be enough

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"Hardcoding the FileHandler pattern" might not be such a bad thing, since the pattern can contain tokens that are replaced at runtime.  I know %t is replaced by whatever the VM believes is the system temp directory (like /var/tmp or C:\\TEMP), %h is the user's home directory (or rather the "user.home" system property), and there are some more but I don't know all of them.

If you use some of those, the pattern might be sufficiently generic that you don't have to worry about trying to super-generalize it for portability.